# Unable to set transfer function on Matlab Simulink

Tags: transfer-function, matlab

I am trying to design a P controller for which I need a transfer function.  I am unable to set a second order equation in the denominator.

When I do, it shows num(s)/den(s) written inside the transfer function block, while when I write any first order equation in denominator, the same transfer function appears written inside the box exactly.

[image: P controller]

Comment: I didn't know the box was retractable, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that I just had to enlarge the transfer function block size by stretching it, because the box was too small to show second order equation in denominator.
[image: P controller]